# NSString search for substring/ csv File IO

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-io, if-statement, substring

This has given me quite a big headache. For whatever reason, when I use this code, the if statement always evaluates to false:

```
while(!feof(file))
{
    NSString *line = [self readNSString:file];
    NSLog(@"%@", line);
    NSLog(@"%@", search);
    NSRange textRange;
    textRange =[line rangeOfString:search];

    if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *result = [line substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange([line rangeOfString:search])];
        resultView.text = result;
    }
    else
    {
        resultView.text = @"Not found";
    }
}
```

When the functions execute, the two NSLogs tell me that the "line" and "search" strings are what they should be, so then why does the if statement always evaluate to false? I must be missing something simple, having another set of eyes would be great. Thanks

edit: (function "readNSString")

```
- (NSString*)readNSString:(FILE*) file
{
    char buffer[300];

    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:256];
    int read;
    do
    {
        if(fscanf(file, "%299[^\n]%n%*c", buffer, &read) == 1)
            [result appendFormat:@"%s", buffer];
        else
            break;
    } while(r == 299);

    return result;
}
```

edit 2:

search is set with a call to the first function, with an NSString* variable as a parameter, like this:

```
NSString *textFieldText = [[NSString alloc]
                              initWithFormat:@"%@", textField.text];

[self readFile:textFieldText];
```

edit 3 (NSLogs output)

line: Germany Italy France

search: Italy

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Read a CSV file?

Comment: Can you show how "search" is set? What are you seeing to make you sure that it is set to what it should be?

Comment: search is set by assigning the text of a textfield to an nsstring. the  NSLog in the first function I posted displays the number I send to it when the function is run

Comment: Can you show the NSLog output?

Comment: Yep, show the output of those two NSLogs.

Comment: see my other edit.... weird, isn't it? try out the code if you like, tell me if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are using the `rangeOfString` and the `NSNotFound` etc. correctly, so the problem is possibly to do with the creation of the string from the data read from the file using the `appendFormat:@"%s"`.

I suspect there may be an encoding issue between your two string formats - I would investigate whether the "%s" encodes the null terminated C string properly into the same format as a unicode `NSString` with the appropriate encoding.

Try hard coding the value you are getting from the `readNSString` function as a string literal in code just for testing and see if that comparison works, if so this would tend to indicate it probably is something to do with the encoding of the string created from the file.